# How do I directly link to the Apex Report "export as CSV" option?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have an Apex report. I turned the option of exporting it as a CSV on. When I run the report, there is a link at the bottom of the page to export the report as a CSV. I would like to put this link on another webpage. When I mouse over the link to get the url, it ends up being something like this:

```
http://server_name/userconsole/f?p=200:5:3692634689183338:FLOW_EXCEL_OUTPUT_R1366308279703792_en-us'
```

When I use this as a link to the export option the exported report is empty. Every time I run the report through Apex, the URL for the "Export As CSV" link changes. Specifically it is this part that changes:

> :3692634689183338:

How would I directly link to the export as CSV option? I am using Apex 4.0.2.00.07.

Edit:

I get this error now when I substituted in `&SESSION.`:

```
Bad Request 

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

mod_plsql: /userconsole/f HTTP-400 Missing '=' in query string or post form
```

In the web address bar, the session id has not replaced `&SESSION.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That segment is your session ID. In your other page substitute `&SESSION.` for that segment:

```
f?p=200:5:&SESSION.:FLOW_EXCEL_OUTPUT_R1366308279703792_en-us'
```

This is well documented in the user guide: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/concept_url.htm#HTMDB03017

Comment: I get this error now when I substituted in "&SESSION.": Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
mod_plsql: /userconsole/f HTTP-400 Missing '=' in query string or post form

Comment: @DiZou I need more information. Is the link you are embedding in another Apex page or in some other non-Apex page? If in Apex, how are you setting this link, as a string, as a branch? If you are presenting the link from a non-Apex page you should then set this segment to 0, as in `http://server_name/userconsole/f?p=200:5:0:FLOW_EXCEL_OUTPUT_R1366308279703792_en-us` However, from a non-Apex environment authentication will not work (if the page has authentication).

Comment: I am presenting the link from a non-Apex page. I tried setting the Session to 0 and the link works now, but the report still has no data.

Comment: @DiZou Why your report has no data becomes a different question. But I assume your report relies on parameters either in session state or passed explicitly to the report. You will probably need to supply any needed parameters or page items via the URL. The documentation link I supplied explains how to do that.